# LiveCode 7.0 (rc 2) standalone compile (strange error)

Tags: livecode

I am using LiveCode 7.0 (rc 2) and compiled my stack as a standalone for Windows 7. I got an elaborate error that (along with a slew of numeric data) included references to the stack "reSaveAsStandalone" and subdirectory /Toolset/revstandalonesettings.rev.

I have tried tweaking my standalone settings to no avail. I've really never had this problem before. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the error said `reSaveAsStandalone`and not `revSaveAsStandalone`?

Answer (score 0):

LiveCode 7.0 is available as a stable release now, (rc2) is a pre-release test version, so I would recommend downloading the latest version and trying again.

<sup>Without the numbers it's difficult to say what the error related to, so if you could try again using the latest version and report back with all details if it still fails, then somebody may be able to help.</sup>

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @mmichael It may be an acceptable answer to suggest upgrading. I will single out the comment part.

Answer (score 0):

here is the bug report.  It has been addressed.  http://quality.runrev.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13851

The error is in the code of the IDE as far as I was told.